# Update db from model in entity framework

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I have a data model created, from which I generated a database, if I have to make any changes in my model, how do I update the database generated?. The RE-generate process is useless for me, because database already contain data. I'm using Visual Studio 2010, EF 4.0, SQL 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142/update-database-schema-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can change your model and DB manually (create/change columns and tables by hand, using SQL Managemets Studio), just delete hash value in EdmMetadata table and EF will not track if your DB is in sync with model anymore. This is quick and dirty solution and you need to take care to keep model in sync with db manually.

Alternatively, you can update to EF 4.3 and take advantage of migrations feature. There are detailed walkthroughs available on: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx